# Python. AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute for the words

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
GREETING_KEYWORDS = ("hello", "hi", "greetings", "sup", "whats up",)
GREETING_RESPONSES = ["sup bro", "hey", "*nods*", "hey you get my snap?"]
def check_for_greeting(sentence):
    for word in sentence.words:
        if word.lower() in GREETING_KEYWORDS:
             return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
user= input(">>> ")
check_for_greeting(user)
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'words'.
>   sentence.words is not proper. How to get the GREETING_RESPONSES if user is giving input in GREETING_KEYWORDS. I am using python 3.5

Comment: What made you think `str` had an attribute `words` ?

Comment: what you don't understand from the error message?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'words'. sentence.words is not proper. How to get the GREETING_RESPONSES if user is giving input in GREETING_KEYWORDS. I am using python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `sentence` is a *string*. I know that the *intention* is that it is a sentence with words in it, but as far as Python is concerned it is only a string with characters in it. `sentence` only contains "words" because you intend that `" "` is a special character that divides the characters in the string into words. You have to tell Python about that intention. Use the `split()` method to do that:

```
def check_for_greeting(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        if word.lower() in GREETING_KEYWORDS:
```